# Solving a sum using Cauchy's sequence

Tags: cauchy-sequences

could I get some help proving that the sum of this expression is equal to $m$ using Cauchy's criterion?

$ 1+\frac{m-1}{m}+(\frac{m-1}{m})^{2}+(\frac{m-1}{m})^{3}+(\frac{m-1}{m})^{4}+....+(\frac{m-1}{m})^{n} $

Comment: What $\;M\;$ do you mean?

Comment: Cauchy's criterion is a way of determining whether or not a series converges. It has nothing to do with actually computing the sum.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I see, thanks! so how could I compute this sum?

Comment: The limit of that sum (over $\;n\;$) is infinity and thus the limit doesn't exist finitely. Have you studied infinite series?

Comment: That's a geometrical series, right?! So…

Comment: Ah, right. Jose Carlos is right, I got confused with the $\;m,\,n\;$ . It is a geom. series with absolute value of ratio less than one and thus it converges...

Answer (score 1):

With geometric series:

$1+\frac{m-1}{m}+(\frac{m-1}{m})^{2}+(\frac{m-1}{m})^{3}+(\frac{m-1}{m})^{4}+....+(\frac{m-1}{m})^{n} \to \frac{1}{1-\frac{m-1}{m}}=m$ as $ n \to \infty.$